# Uploading a Nuget Package Manually in Teamcity feed

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I am building a new Teamcity project which has dependency on a package which is generated by different project in same Teamcity server. But I can't build the project which generates the nuget package and upload the nuget package manually in Teamcity server so that my other project can reference same and can build. is this possible ? and how i can achieve same.